# Prove or disprove that $G$ and $U(20)$ are isomorphic

Tags: group-theory

I am having a problem with the following question.

Question: Let $G$ be the permutation group 
$$ \{(1),(1 \ 2),(3 \ 4),(1 \ 2)(3 \ 4), (5 \ 6), (1 \ 2)(5 \ 6), (3 \ 4)(5 \ 6), (1 \ 2)(3 \ 4)(5 \ 6) \} $$
Prove or disprove that $G$ and $U(20)$ are isomorphic.

I know that $G$ and $U(20)$ are not isomorphic, and below is my proof. I am just not sure that my solution really proves that they are not isomorphic. I would really love your insight. Thanks

My solution:  Notice that $\forall x \in G$, $x^2 = I$ where $I$ = identity. However, for $a \in U(20)$, $a^2 \neq 1$. For example: for $a=1,9,11,19$ $a^2 = 1$. However, for $a =3,7,13,17$ $a^2=9$. So $G$ cannot be isomorphic to $U(20)$.

Comment: Well, what *is* your solution? Without knowing that we cannot really tell you if it is correct.

Comment: Hey I am sorry, I was trying to type it. I didnt expect you would replay that fast. Thank you I really appreciate your quick response!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is right but can be written more clearly as

> $U(20)$ has an element of order $4$ but $G$ does not.

The justification is that isomorphisms preserve the order of elements and so isomorphic groups have the same number of elements of any given order. (But [this is not enough for groups to be isomorphic](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/39848/finite-groups-with-elements-of-the-same-order).)

Comment: Thank you very much, I totally forgot about that property. I have now used that fact in the proof aswell. Thank you very much for your help :)